# Configuration name from SNOW - Uipath Windows

Tags: jquery, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api, uipath-activity

I am trying to collect the data from Service now using Uipath application. Since windows legacy is moving away, I am trying to get the data in snow in Windows.

[image]

I am trying to filter the Change request number with the configuration item. Say if configuration item is "abc", I wanted to see all the change request which has the configuration item "abc" and wanted between two date ranges.
Currently I am trying to get the configuration item alone, for which I have used to below query:

```
`sysparm_fields=number,cmdb_ci`
```

If I execute this query I am getting the following result: Screenshot attached[image]
From this I would like to get only the value in name, ie (like "abc"). I have tried giving the query like

```
`sysparm_fields=number,cmdb_ci.name`
   ` sysparm_fields=number,cmdb_ci.value-name`
    `sysparm_fields=number,cmdb_ci.name-value`
```

and in other possible ways, but not sure what could be the exact data to use to retrieve the configuration item name. Please let me know how to get this fixed. Thanks in advance.

I have tried giving the query like
`

```
 sysparm_fields=number,cmdb_ci.name`
   ` sysparm_fields=number,cmdb_ci.value-name`
    `sysparm_fields=number,cmdb_ci.name-value`
```

and in other possible ways, but not sure what could be the exact data to use to retrieve the configuration item name. Needing the configuration item name